# How do I get AWS CDK stack env values for bootstrapping an environment?

Tags: aws-cdk

AWS and other sources consider explicitly specifying the AWS account and region for each stack as best practice.  I'm trying to write a CI pipeline that will bootstrap my environments.  However, I'm not seeing any straight-forward way to retrieve the stack's explicit env values from here:

```
regions.forEach((region) => 
  new DbUpdateStack(app, `${stackBaseName}-prd-${region}`, {
    env: { 
      account: prdAccount, 
      region: region 
    },
    environment_instance: 'prd',
    vpc_id: undefined,
  })
);
```

EG, base-name-prd-us-east-1 knows the region and account as defined in the code but how do I access this from the command line without doing something hacky?

I need to run cdk bootstrap with those values and I don't want to duplicate them.

Comment: FYI calling `cdk bootstrap` from your CDK folder will bootstrap all the environments defined in the app.

Answer (score 0):

The [Cloud Assembly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_cx-api.CloudAssembly.html) module can introspect an App's stack environments. Synth the app, then instantiate a CloudAssembly class by pointing at the cdk output directory:

```js
import * as cx_api from '@aws-cdk/cx-api';

(() => {
  const cloudAssembly = new cx_api.CloudAssembly('cdk.out');
  const appEnvironments = cloudAssembly.stacks.map(stack => stack.environment);

  console.log(appEnvironments);
})();
```

Result:

```js
[
  {
    account: '123456789012',
    region: 'us-east-1',
    name: 'aws://123456789012/us-east-1',
  },
];
```